# Axis 1.7.1 dependency issue - error in generated stub class

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis, maven-plugin

i'm new to Web services, Axis 2 and maven, but i will need it for my master-thesis. I have successfully created and tested a SOAP Web service like in this Tutorial: [Web service Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrW8iqk50MU)

Now i want to create a MavenProject, where i'm able to create the client classes and stubs for this service like in this tutorial: [Client Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-h0ioC7Cb4) by using the ***axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin***. The generation works fine, but i get everytime an error in the Stub-class.

The error is: ***org.apache.axis2.xmlbeans cannot be resolved to a type***. This is the only error i get in the Stub. This ist for example a method, where the error appears (line 5 *org.apache.axis2.xmlbeans.XmlBeansXMLReader*):

```
private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(
    final com.mycompany.axisservice3.SayOnlyOneHelloDocument param)
    throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
    org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLParserWrapper builder = org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(new javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource(
                new org.apache.axis2.xmlbeans.XmlBeansXMLReader(param,
                    _xmlOptions), new org.xml.sax.InputSource()));

    try {
        return builder.getDocumentElement(true);
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
    }
}
```

The remaining generated classes have no errors and seem to be okay.

So I think it must be a dependency issue, because the system can not find the package ***org.apache.axis2.xmlbeans***. I'm using the latest version of Apache **Axis 2 (1.7.1)** and Maven 2. So i have adjusted the dependencies from the video to the latest version from Maven Repository-Website.

Axis2 Runtime is loaded succesfully and configured in eclipse. Path and Environment Variables are set.

Here is my current POM for the client:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.andy</groupId>
<artifactId>AxisService3Client</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                        <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                        <packageName>org.andy.ws</packageName>
                        <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I am running into the issue where I can not find org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.writer package in axis2-adb-1.7.9 jar. Is there any replacement you are aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add below dependencies,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
           <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then project got build successfully.